# How do you gain Mana for weapons which only contain Healing Abilities?

Tags: phantom-brave

I have equipped Marona with a staff with nothing but healing abilities. after unlocking the Blacksmith i find out her weapon has "Mega Heal" which could come in handy later on.

So far the only why i know of in gaining Mana is to kill enemies as the only other weapon i have is a sword that Ash initially has equipped (but after he has to return i re-confine the original object and my second phantom has the sword equipped) and it's been the only weapon to gain any Mana throughout Episode 1 despite me having brought both weapons at the same time (and both have been in the same number of battles)

So how do i gain Mana for a weapon which has only healing abilities?

Comment: There's definitely away to do it, but I forget how unfortunately. Maybe just healing people with it will work.

Comment: @RossRidge check that last night but unfortunately it didn't work, i used every healing ability at least once in a battle and still only my sword got Mana

Comment: I remember you can just fuse weapons with mana into another weapon to get mana.  It's been a LONG time since I played this, and the console isn't currently available to me.

Later on when I start capturing weapons, I just don't bother "levelling" weapons like that anymore.  I just merge a pile of stuff together and then it becomes uber.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Nelson, your best bet is to merge weapons into the staff. It will also let you add non-healing abilities to it. A good way to get high-mana items is to use a Bottlemail and the Failure Title trick to gain powerful items full of mana from weakened enemies. As a bonus, you also get a substantial amount of Exp and Mana for the characters. The only drawback is that Marona doesn't gain experience in this way, so she'll start falling behind the others.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways

- Don't equip the staff, leave it on the island. Items not taken into battle will gain some mana from time to time. But that's a really slow way to do it.
- Get another staff with an attack ability (a good low-level choice would be *Blinding Light* which is an attack spell but uses the healing magic skill), collect some mana with that staff and then use your Fusionist (unlocked in battle 1 of chapter 2) to move the attack spell onto the healing staff.
- Collect some mana with other offense-oriented items (it doesn't matter what type of item or who uses it) and then have your Fusionist fuse them into the staff without taking any skills or stat enhancements. When you fuse two items, the resulting item will have the sum of the mana points of both items (minus the cost for any stats or skills you transferred).